# std::vector reallocations in transactional way: copy and move constructors

Tags: c++, c++11

In this question I want to clarify some details about `std::vector` reallocations in C++11 and further. I have a class `Data` with all defined contructors and I'm putting objects of this class to `std::vector`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Data
{
    Data()
    {
        std::cout << "[Data]\n";
    }
    explicit Data(int v)
        : ptr(new int(v))
    {
        std::cout << "[Data] v: " << v << "\n";
    }

    ~Data()
    {
        if (ptr)
            delete ptr;
        std::cout << "[~Data]\n";
    }

    Data(const Data& rhs)
    {
        std::cout << "[Data] copy cntr\n";
        *this = rhs;
    }

    Data& operator=(const Data& rhs)
    {
        if (this != &rhs)
        {
            if (rhs.ptr)
                ptr = new int(*rhs.ptr);
        }

        return *this;
    }

    Data(Data&& rhs) noexcept
    {
        *this = std::move(rhs);
        std::cout << "[Data] move cntr\n";
    }

    Data& operator=(Data&& rhs) noexcept
    {
        if (this != &rhs)
        {
            ptr = rhs.ptr;
            rhs.ptr = nullptr;
        }

        return *this;
    }

private:
    int* ptr = nullptr;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Data> values;
    values.emplace_back(1);
    values.emplace_back(2);
    values.emplace_back(3);
    values.emplace_back(4);

    std::cout << "------\n";
    return 0;
}
```

After the execution we have the following output:

```
[Data] v: 1
[Data] v: 2
[Data] move cntr
[~Data]
[Data] v: 3
[Data] move cntr
[Data] move cntr
[~Data]
[~Data]
[Data] v: 4
------
[~Data]
[~Data]
[~Data]
[~Data]
```

Everything is clear here. During vector Reallocations `move_if_noexcept` is called under ther hood because move constructor is noexcept:

```
Data(Data&& rhs) noexcept
```

Move operation can be done transactionally. If I delete noexcept:

```
Data(Data&& rhs)
```

I will have the following output:

```
[Data] v: 1
[Data] v: 2
[Data] copy cntr
[~Data]
[Data] v: 3
[Data] copy cntr
[Data] copy cntr
[~Data]
[~Data]
[Data] v: 4
------
[~Data]
[~Data]
[~Data]
[~Data]
```

Copy constructor will be called (fallback to copy) to guarantee vector reallocation that can be done transactionally. And the moment that I really do not understand. If I explicitly delete copy constructor and assigment:

```
Data(const Data& rhs) = delete;
Data& operator=(const Data& rhs) = delete;
```

The output will be the following in spite of the fact that move construct in not `noexcept`:

```
[Data] v: 1
[Data] v: 2
[Data] move cntr
[~Data]
[Data] v: 3
[Data] move cntr
[Data] move cntr
[~Data]
[~Data]
[Data] v: 4
------
[~Data]
[~Data]
[~Data]
[~Data]
```

Does it means that in this way we do not have any guarantees about reallocations that can be done transactionally (move constructor can throw exception and vector will be in invalid state)? Is it ok? My expectation is to get compile error in this case.

Comment: OT: `if (ptr) delete ptr;` — the check for null pointer is superfluous here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When copy constructor is not available, `std::vector` has no other option than to use move constructor, even if it may throw. <s>In such a case, there is only [*basic exception safety*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_safety) guaranteed (suppose destructor cannot throw).</s>

<s>Note that a vector won't be in an *invalid state*, it will be in a valid state, but its contents may be different than before reallocation. Such as, it may be empty but still usable.</s>

It actually seems that the effect in such a case is *unspecified*. The question is, whether a vector may or may not be used in such situations and whether elements are guaranteed to be destructed.